# Is git-blame available on smartgit?

Tags: smartgit

I am searching for a way to use git blame through smartgit UI. 
Is it available or am I searching for a missing feature?

**UPDATE:**
Available with SmartGitHg4 http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/whatsnew.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blame/Annotate is not yet present in SmartGit, but will be with the next major release.

Comment: Is there a place where I can see whats coming in next version?

Comment: Usually early-access builds are published at: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/early-access.html . You may also consider to follow syntevo on twitter to get informed on new versions.

Comment: This is what I am using to see the git commands `tail -f "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\syntevo\SmartGit\3\log.txt" | grep "git.exe" | cut -d " " -f 13-`

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I still can't find/see any Git Blame in File Compare window.

Comment: @RajaniKaruturi it's not in the File Compare, but in the main window: Query Blame